# Adding a New Line on Facebook Comment

Tags: facebook, formatting

When I am commenting on Facebook, how do I insert a new line. Let us say, that I post a status. Friend A comments on it, followed by Friend B, followed by Friend C.

I am now posting a reply and I want it formatted as follows.

> @FriendA: ..........
>
> @FriendB: ..........
>
> @FriendC: ..........

If I were to press Enter after I have written the response for FriendA, it posts that message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a newline, simply type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will insert a newline character (thus making a new line) rather than enter, which causes the form to submit.

Note that in some cases, Facebook strips newline characters, and it isn't consistent. For example, you can type newlines into status updates, and it will show the line breaks on your wall and in the newsfeed, but not at the top of your profile.

Answer (score 4):

When adding a comment in a new-style group, there is no Comment button; you just press Enter to submit the comment.  You can press Shift-Enter to insert a new line.

I have only seen this in the new-style groups.  Old-style groups, as well as profiles and Pages, still use the Comment button, at least for me.  However it may be that Facebook is planning to gradually roll out the change everywhere.